# Sharing text and Url to Facebook Messenger with UIActivityViewController but failing

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-messenger, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share both text and url to Facebook Messenger using UIActivityViewController.
But when i success send and open my Messenger, i only get url.
Is it possible send text and url to Facebook Messenger using UIActivityViewController at the same time?

Here is my code

```
@IBAction func sharedLink(_ sender: Any) {
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com.tw")!
        let text = "test" as AnyObject
        let shareObject: [AnyObject] = [text, url as AnyObject]
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareObject, applicationActivities: [])
        vc.completionWithItemsHandler = { (type,completed,items,error) in
            if completed { vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }
        }
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[Here is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmssD.jpg)

Comment: Combine text and link into a single string using /n to keep URL into a separate line. Then pass it to the array.

Comment: @nitin.agam thank you for your answer sincerely

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

```swift
@IBAction func sharedLink(_ sender: Any) {
        let urlString = "https://www.google.com.tw"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let text = "test" as AnyObject
        let shareObject: [AnyObject] = ["\(text), \(urlString)"]
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareObject, applicationActivities: [])
        vc.completionWithItemsHandler = { (type,completed,items,error) in
            if completed { vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }
        }
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32922542)